# Excel return true if number is within range

Tags: excel, search, vlookup

**My problem**

I have a list of values (List 1) that have the following pattern...

`1234-COD-125`

I have another list (List 2), which follow the pattern...

`12345(1234-COD-100 - 1234-COD-150)`

I need to search List 2 and return True if the value in List 1 is within range. So for example..

```
List 1         Result       List 2
1234-COD-125    TRUE        12345(1234-COD-100 - 1234-COD-150)
1234-COD-126    TRUE        12345(4567-BAH-100 - 4567-BAH-150)
1234-COD-155    FALSE
4567-BAH-125    TRUE        
4567-BAH-126    TRUE
4567-BAH-155    FALSE
```

**Background**

The first part (`1234-COD`) is the vendor ID and code. The last part (`125`) is the order ID. Different vendors can have the same order ID, so my lookup needs to account for the vendor.

**What I've done so far**

I have written a series of formulas which extract parts of the string. For instance, for

`12345(1234-COD-100 - 1234-COD-150)`

I have extracted the following in individual cells

`100`

`150`

`COD`

`1234-COD-100`

`1234-COD-150`

I know I can create a series to manually populate each order ID within range, then perform a lookup but I have hundreds of values in List 2 so this isn't an option.

Another option is to take the value in List 2 (`12345(1234-COD-100 - 1234-COD-150`) and check if every number in the range 100-150 is found in List 1.

I would like to be able to use a formula (or even VBA) to achieve this, but haven't been able to get any further. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Will those IDs always have 12 chars?

Comment: No, they can have more or less

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing text is always problematic.  The following will return what you want:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2>=TRIM(LEFT(MID($C$2:$C$3,FIND("(",$C$2:$C$3)+1,LEN($C$2:$C$3)),FIND(" - ",MID($C$2:$C$3,FIND("(",$C$2:$C$3)+1,LEN($C$2:$C$3)))-1)))*(A2<=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID($C$2:$C$3,FIND(" - ",$C$2:$C$3)+3,LEN($C$2:$C$3))),")","")))>0
```

[image]

But it depends exclusively on the pattern you are showing. Specifically that the range is always in `()` and the two ranges are separated by `-`

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Worked perfectly